# ¿Como detectar cuando dejamos de escribir en un input?

Tags: html, angular, ionic4

quería hacer mi primer aporte, estoy trabajando con Ionic 4.
En este caso quiero mostrar como detectar cuando dejamos de escribir en un input y así ejecutar una fracción de código cuando pasa un determinado tiempo.

```js
filterItems(ev) 
  {    
    this.spin = true;  // Variable boolean para mostrar ion-spinner
    this.timeLeft = 1; // Variable number del temporizador, se renueva cada vez que se ejectuta el metodo (al teclear sobre el campo)
    if(!this.flag)
    {
      this.flag = true;  // variable boolean para generar un solo intervalo
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        if(this.timeLeft > 0) 
        {
          this.timeLeft--;
        } 
        else 
        {
          clearInterval(this.interval);
          this.spin = false;      
          this.flag = false; 

          console.log('Metodo a ejecutar ' + ev)  // Fracción de código a ejecutar
        }        
      },500)  // Tiempo en ms en que se ejecutará la fracción de código dentro el intervalo cuando dejamos de teclear
    }    
   }
```

```html
 <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-1">              
          <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-6 offset-lg-6" (keyup)="filterItems($event)"/>
          <ion-spinner name="lines-small" class="spinner" *ngIf="spin"></ion-spinner>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Espero les sirva de ayuda :)

Comment: Esta información la tienes que entregar en formato pregunta-respuesta. Tu pregunta sería ¿Cómo detectar cuando dejamos de escribir en un input?. Luego ingresas una respuesta a tu propia pregunta y la aceptas.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario !, lo tendré en cuenta

Comment: Si no la modificas, voy a tener que cerrarla porque no es una pregunta...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un observable con un `formControl`

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-1">              
        <input 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control col-lg-6 offset-lg-6" 
            [formControl]="search"
        />
        <ion-spinner name="lines-small" class="spinner" *ngIf="spin"></ion-spinner>
    </div>
</div>
```

y en tu archivo TS hacer esto

```
    public search: FormControl = new FormControl('');


   constructor() {
      this.search.valueChanges
        .pipe(
          tap(() => (this. spin = true)),
          debounceTime(500) // tiempo que quieres que espere
        )
        .subscribe(v => {
          this.spin = false;
          console.log(v);
       });
   }
```